# A memory leak in +initialize

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments

Instruments reports a 100% leak in this method:

```
+(void)initialize{
    mapper = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

Assuming that Instruments doesn't report false positives, what possible scenarios could lead to this? Multi-threading (although the docs say it's called in a "thread-safe manner")?

This is non-ARC.

Comment: Instruments *does* sometimes report false positives. (However, this one is actually a leak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there were subclasses of this class above. Setting up the `alloc`s in `initialize` in a `dispatch_once` block fixed the leaks.

[This post](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-05-22-objective-c-class-loading-and-initialization.html) from Mike Ash helped in figuring out `initialize`.

Comment: I tried the above answers, but our leaks didn't disappear until we did this. The class that we were using had subclasses though, so this solution might not apply in all cases. Accept your own answer, @raheel!

Answer (score 2):

The problem (assuming a non-ARC environment) is that you allocate the memory for `mapper` but you never release it.

Comment: True, but where would you deallocate it anyway? `dealloc` is obviously out. That is, it doesn't make sense to deallocate it.

Answer (score 1):

use an autorelease pool:

```
+(void)initialize {
    @autoreleasepool {
      mapper = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
}
```

in this case, creation of the object can result in autoreleased object (e.g. internal or temporary within NSMutableDictionary's implementation). of course, if this were the problem, you would see "…autoreleased with no pool in place -- just leaking" messages in the console.

you should also consider initializing your shared/global stuff lazily, or after your app's done launching.

if you don't see those messages, then this would not apply.

Comment: The idea is that this object will be used across threads, and creating it in `initialize` allows us to make sure there is only one instance, and is created in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: @Justin won't this object be released at an undefined time, breaking the code?

Comment: @raheel ensuring that initialization happens only once does not require you to initialize when your image (app) is loaded (that is before main even enters). see examples of `pthread_once()`.

Comment: @Justin I didn't see the autorelease pool message.

Comment: @H2CO3 it won't break the code. just as before, `mapper` won't ever be released, or it will be explicitly released when the designated destruction routine for the global is called. so, it will not introduce a change. although the memory will of course be returned to the OS after the process exits.

Comment: @raheel alright - you may want to try it, anyways. (maybe the message changed?). what objects are being leaked? the dictionary itself, or objects supporting the dictionary?